# What will the powers of the The Indigenous Australian Voice be?

Tags: constitution, australia, indigenous-people

Australia is considering a referendum to alter its constitution to create an "Australian and Torres Strait Islander Voice".

The text of the amendment is as follows:

> - "There shall be a body, to be called the Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander voice."
> - “The Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander voice may make representations to parliament and the executive government on matters
>   relating to Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander peoples."
> - "The parliament shall, subject to this Constitution, have power to make laws with respect to the composition, functions, powers and
>   procedures of the Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander voice."

Will the "power" clause in the third paragraph allow the Voice to wield executive and legislative powers beyond its stated "advisory" role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the parliament can decide that. They can make (and repeal) laws which give the Indigenous Voice as much (or as little) legislative and executive power as the parliament wants. The only constitutional limitation is that they can not abolish the body altogether or take away the right to "make representations to parliament and the executive government". Everything else is not constitutionally guaranteed.

The [Indigenous Voice Co-design Process Final Report](https://voice.niaa.gov.au/sites/default/files/2021-12/indigenous-voice-co-design-process-final-report_1.pdf) proposes that National Voice only provides non-binding advise to the government and parliament. So that will probably be the arrangement for the time being.

There are also local and regional voices which are supposed to be integrated with local and regional governments on all levels. How those partnerships are arranged in detail is also subject to regional politics. But the proposal reads:

> Local & Regional Voices will not displace or
> undermine bodies with existing statutory
> roles or specific functions but provide links
> for involvement.

So they are also intended to have an advisor role for existing government organs and not to wield any direct power.